# Is there a way to track down where the class autoloading triggered at?

Tags: php, namespaces, autoload

Is there a way to track down where the class autoloading triggered at? I meant I want to know which file, line refers to the class/interface. Where its began to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure if you use `debug_print_backtrace()` or such in your autoload function, this should show you where it's being called from, allowing you to track down where the first usage was.